# NotFound cannot be converted to Throwable

Tags: java, generics, exception

I want to achieve one objective. I am sharing my concept with demo code.

```
interface NotFound{
        //define one marker interface which will mark not found  
    }

class ServiceException extends RuntimeException{

}

class TeacherServiceException extends ServiceException{

}


class TeacherNotFoundException extends TeacherServiceException
implements NotFound{
    TeacherNotFoundException(){
    //if teacher is null then will throw this type of exception
   }
}


class StudentServiceException extends ServiceException{

}


class StudentNotFoundException extends StudentServiceException
implements NotFound{
    StudentNotFoundException(){
    //if student is null then will throw this type of exception
   }
}


interface HasName{
    void addName(String name);
} 


//these are the models
class Student implements HasName{

    @Override
    public void addName(String name){


    }

}


class Teacher implements HasName{
    @Override
    public void addName(String name){

    }
}

//these are the resources 


class StudentResource{

    StudentService service = new StudentService(null);

    NameSupportResource<TeacherService> support = new NameSupportResource<>();

    void addName(String name){

        support.addName(service,name);
    }

}

class TeacherResource{

    TeacherService service = new TeacherService(null);

    NameSupportResource<TeacherService> support = new NameSupportResource<>();

    void addName(String name){

        support.addName(service,name);

    }
}

class NameSupportResource<T extends HasNameService>{

    void addName(T service,String name){

        try{
            service.addName(name);
        }
        catch(NotFound e){

        }

    }
}

//these are the services

interface HasNameService<T extends HasName>{

    T addName(String name);
}

class StudentService implements HasNameService<Student>{

    Student student;

    StudentService(Student student){

        this.student = student;
    }

    @Override

    public Student addName(String name){

        if(student ==  null)
            throw new StudentNotFoundException();
        else{

            student.addName(name);

            return student; 
        }

    }

}


class TeacherService implements HasNameService<Teacher>{

    Teacher teacher;

    TeacherService(Teacher teacher){

        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    @Override
    public Teacher addName(String name){

        if(teacher ==  null)
            throw new TeacherNotFoundException();
        else{

            teacher.addName(name);

            return teacher;
        }

    }

}
```

Here you can see that if studnet is null or teacher is null then it can throw `StudentNotFoundException` or `TeacherNotFoundException` respectively.

The purpose of using `NameSupportResource` is to make common. because in future i can introduce another model like `Student` or `Teacher` they can have same name add operation. Now if any model is null i want to throw sub type exception i.e. `StudentNotFoundException`. Let say i want to introduce another model i.e. book, and if book is null then i will throw `BookNotFoundException`. But i want to catch it by parent type. That is why i have defined maker interface. As we know an interface can point to class object.

But i have seen one error

```
incompatible types: NotFound cannot be converted to Throwable
        catch(NotFound e){
              ^
1 error
```

Can you tell me how i can solve it??

Comment: `NotFound` doesn't extend `Throwable` (nor can it, because it's an interface). That's the long, short and middle of it.

Comment: `NotFound` is not a `Throwable`, nor an `Exception`, nor a `RuntimeException`. You can't use it in a `catch`.

Comment: @AndyTurner i understand that. but i want to figure out a way to solve the design pattern

Comment: Please see this scenario. I have edited in exception section.

Comment: Have `NotFound` extend `Throwable` or one of its children.

Answer (score 4):

You can only `throw` and `catch` objects that are subtypes of `Throwable` (typically subtypes of `Exception` or `RuntimeException`).

As these are classes and we don't have multiple inheritance in Java, this means you have to fit your exceptions under just one hierarchy.

If your `NotFound` is a specific `ServiceException`, you can model it like that (also, you might want to add an `Exception` suffix to follow convention):

```
class NotFoundException extends ServiceException
```

Then, have your other "not found" exceptions extend this one, like:

```
class TeacherNotFoundException extends NotFoundException
```

(note that `TeacherNotFoundException` is also a `ServiceException` as well)

You'll then be able to catch all your "not found" exceptions as:

```
catch(NotFoundException e){
}
```

Comment: Please see this scenario. I have edited in exception section.

Comment: I see that your scenario includes also a ServiceException. I updated my answer accordingly. @SubhabrataMondal

Answer (score 0):

from Java Doc [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html)

> catch block is an exception handler that handles the type of exception indicated by its argument. The argument type, ExceptionType, declares the type of exception that the handler can handle and must be the name of a **class that inherits from the Throwable class**. The handler can refer to the exception with name.

so if you want to catch **NotFound** in catch block then it should inherits from **Throwable**.